# How to fetch the old records from the mongo after the schema change

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have an existing schema like

```
exports.OldCollectionSchema= new Schema({
Id: { type: Schema.ObjectId },
parentId: { type: Schema.ObjectId },
userId: { type : String }, 
userName: { type : String })
```

Now, I waned to use the above collection in two scenarios by adding a new field `type`

type would be scenario a or scenario b

so I wanted to fetch the old records + type = "scenario a" and to show that in a page

How is it possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do believe Mongoose has a `__v` field denoting version however I am no Mongoose expert so I will just paste the easy hacky query that you can do:

```
db.col.find({type: {$exists: false, $in: ['a']}});
```

That will basically say: *"Get all the records where they don't yet have a scenario (basically the ones before this schema) and combine them with the ones that have a type of 'a'"*

#### Edit

Actually a better way is just to use `null` here:

```
db.col.find({type: {$in: ['a', null]}});
```

Comment: `__v` is for Mongoose's internal use in tracking array field edits so it shouldn't be used for this sort of thing.  The first solution listed here won't work but the one in your edit looks good.

Comment: Ah yea should have used an `$or` there, meh the second one is much better anyway.